# String concat doesnt work

Tags: java, string

When I use string.concat(something.toString()); it doesnt works but on the other hand if i do simple concatenation it works.

For example

```
Integer x = 5;
String y = "Number is : ";    
y.concat(x.toString());
System.out.println(y);
```

this output is >> Number is :

but if I do this >> `y = y + x.toString();`

the output is >> Number is : 5

Comment: String are immutable.

Comment: N.B: `String.concat` is the same as `+` - use that instead.

Comment: `concat` works, but you are using it incorrectly. You need to keep the result instead of discarding.